# update images using Magmi tool in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magmi

I am importing images of products using Magmi Tool. I am confusing that after first import how to import new images and preserve old images.

If I am trying to import base images (image,small_image,thumbnail_image) second time then it's replacing earlier imported images.

for **media gallery** there is **media_gallery_reset** column we need to add to preserve earlier imported images but what about base images?

Is there any solution to not replace all the images imported earlier and just it will add new image to product ?

I am using following Configuration in Magmi

- Image attributes processor v1.0.33
  Image import mode : Override Existing Images
  Assign Only existing images : NO

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Update Image import mode as per screen. IF u wants to remove use '-'(minus) sign before image.

use this column for media import & update. sku, thumbnail,  small_image,  image,  media_gallery

[image]

Comment: How can i import images for my multi-store, can i get csv header column values,, my csv : https://snag.gy/e3kioC.jpg